# Extract all multibyte characters from a string in PHP

Tags: php, string, unicode, utf-8

I'm trying to implement a version of `str_word_count()` that works with Asian characters. However, I don't know how to separate the single-byte and multibyte characters in a given UTF-8 string. What function(s) would I use to find multibyte characters in a string?

For example, I may want to split a string along the boundary between single-byte and multibyte characters.

```
'Test中国test中国' => array('Test','中国','test','中国');
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the character encoding is set for the entire string - so either every character in the string is a multibyte character, or none are.  I assume what you're meaning to ask is how to look for non-ASCII characters in a string?

Comment: I thought that characters can have different numbers of bytes in an UTF-8 string? But I guess looking for non-ASCII characters work as well.

Comment: Ah, never mind, that *is* a variable width format...

Answer (score 0):

There are many functions that can do this, in particular the `Multibyte String Functions`, but what is important to note is that all multi-byte characters are counted as 1. Here are a couple examples:

```
$str_en = "test";
$str_ch = '中国';

echo $str_en . " " . (str_word_count($str_en)) . " word(s)" . "\n";
echo $str_ch . " " . (mb_strlen($str_ch,'utf8')) . " word(s)" . "\n"; 
echo mb_strlen($str_ch,'utf8') + str_word_count($str_en) . " word(s) total";
```

output:

```
test 1 word(s)
中国 2 word(s)
3 word(s) total
```

The example above uses `mb_strlen`, while the next example uses `preg_match` to detect non-ascii characters in while looping through an array.

```
$var = array('Test','中国','test','中国');

foreach($var as $char) {
    if (preg_match('/[\x80-\xFF]/', $char, $match)) {
        echo $char . " - " . mb_detect_encoding($char) . " - " .  str_word_count($char) . "word(s) \n";
        /* Detect character encoding with current detect_order */
    } else {
        /* Detect character encoding with current detect_order */
        echo $char . " - " . mb_detect_encoding($char) . " - " .  str_word_count($char) . "word(s) \n";
    }
}
```

print_r($match) . "\n"; // shows only the matching non-ascii chars

output:

```
Test - ASCII - 1 word(s) 
中国 - UTF-8 - 2 word(s) 
test - ASCII - 1 word(s) 
中国 - UTF-8 - 2 word(s)
```